# Php two different array with same keys

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to php and still learning the language,

let say I have two array

**For Example**

```
Array
(
    [house_id] => 6
    [name] => Lake Villa
    [floor] => 5
    [unit] => 25
)

Array
(
    [house_id] => 6
    [name] => Lake Villa
    [floor] => 5
    [unit] => 25
    [parking_id] => 9
    [resident_count] => 4
)
```

How do i get the keys of 1st array onto second, what i am saying is, i just need `house_id, name, floor, unit` from second array and discard rest of the information.

However, they key is not same and dynamic, which means the first array key whatever returned is also present on second but with additional information. The information above is just an example and the keys might varies but whatever key on first array contains on second array too.

I tried this, but isn't working:

```
foreach($arr1 as $k=>$v) {
    foreach($arr2 as $j=>$w) {
        if(isset($arr2[$k]))
            $arr[$k] = $w;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the expected output? I simply don't understand .. sorry

Comment: Have you experimented with array_merge? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: -1 This question should be improved by giving expected output.

Comment: @jack How do i get the keys of 1st array onto second, what i am saying is, i just need house_id, name, floor, unit from second array and discard rest of the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use array_intersect_key, to merge the arrays.

```
$newArray = array_intersect_key($array2, $array1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [array_intersect_key()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php).

> array_intersect_key() returns an array containing all the entries of
> array1 which have keys that are present in all the arguments.

#### Code

```
var_dump(array_intersect_key($array1, $array2));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($arr2 as $key=>$val){
   if(!array_key_exists($key,$arr1))        
   unset($arr2[$key]);
}
```

Comment: would appericiate if you can be done within two array. thanks

Comment: I dont think its better then `array_intersect_key`, but it's alternative.

Answer (score 0):

change condition from

```
if(isset($arr2[$k]))
```

to

```
if($arr1[$k] == $arr2[$j])   // it will work.
```

and `isset` is used for checking the variable is set or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($arr2 as $k=>$v) {
    //Check if key is in first array
    if(!isset($arr1[$k])) {
        //Key not in first array, remove from second array. 
        unset($arr2[$k]); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$result_array = array_intersect_key($arr2, $arr1);
```